# Merging two dlls using DLL2LIB

Tags: visual-studio, dll, linker

i read that it is possible to get rid of dll files by converting them to library files using DLL2LIB and then linking to your program

[DLL2LIB](http://www.ionicwind.com/forums/index.php?topic=1361.0)

i already tried to do that, but the program is still asking me for the dynamic library

not sure i did what i had to do within Visual Studio Express 10

thanks for any help

Jeff

Comment: Converting a program that uses DLLs to a single executable is very common, any Windows user insists on it as well.  The result is called setup.exe, surely you've used one before.  Lots of installer writer utilities out there.

Comment: i don't want to use an istaller, only if i really need to, i would prefer to have one final .DLL with everything packed inside. Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible by converting to a LIB. DLL differs from LIB. For example, there is a startup code placed into a DllMain function.

So I would suggest to google for "exe bundle", you will find some tools to embed DLLs into EXE: http://bit.ly/16jdv0z

Hope this helps.

Comment: i forgot to tell you i'm building a Photoshop plugin so the final program is a .DLL. Sorry about that. Also i already tried : ILMerge MKBundle MonoMerge ILRepack and MergeBin. All with errormessages/not working. Jeff

Comment: I think I know a solution, could you write me to Artem.Razin (at) gmail dot com? I could write a name of solution, but moderators don't like I mention it so often :)